# I want to use Python Fabric with my custom Operator, how should I install fabric on workers?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

At this point I'm thinking about calling bash command `pip install fabric2` each time my operator executed, but this does not looke like a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `requirements.txt` file similar and pass that as a variable while creating the cloud composer enviroment.

Sample `requirements.txt` file:

```
scipy>=0.13.3
scikit-learn
nltk[machine_learning]
```

Pass the `requirements.txt` file to the `environments.set-python-dependencies` command to set your installation dependencies.

```
gcloud beta composer environments update ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
--update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \
--location LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use: `PythonVirtualenvOperator` it supports pip deps.

Another option that is available for the Composer users is to install deps via the composer itself: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies